# настройка в netbeans + openserver xdebug

Tags: php

Установил netbeans 8.2 + openserver 5.2 .  Хочу настроить xdebug, но не выходит. xdebug скачал с сайта, файл перенес в папку C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP-5.5\ext. Вывожу phpinfo, там где должно писать что xdebug  установлен, ничего не пишет.

Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:

### Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

помошите плз.

Comment: А он подключён в php.ini?

Comment: да, подключен!!

Answer (score 0):

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
;xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
;xdebug.collect_params = 4
;xdebug.collect_return = 1
;xdebug.collect_assignments = 1
;xdebug.collect_vars = 1
xdebug.dump.REQUEST = *
xdebug.dump.SESSION = *
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE =
;xdebug.dump.FILES =
;xdebug.dump.GET =
;xdebug.dump.POST =
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
;xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
;xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
;xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.remote_log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/logs"
;xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
;xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.scream = 1
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
;xdebug.trace_format = 1
;xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%H%R"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
```

Comment: Спасибо, больше не нужна помощь, так как сам нашел ошибку и исправил, теперь все работает.

Comment: Напишите как ответ ваш вариант решения или удалите вопрос